# Get a list of possible outbound ip addresses in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-function-app

I'm trying to use the export from a azure function app in terraform to get the possible outbound ip addresses that I can add to a whitelist for a firewall

The parameter returned is a string of ips comma separated.

I have tried using the split function within terraform but it doesn't give a list, it gives an interface which can't be used as a list. I've tried using local scopes to add square brackets around it but still the same.

Let me just add this is terraform 11 not 12.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                        = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-kv"
  location                    = "${azurerm_resource_group.environment.location}"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.environment.name}"
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = "${var.tenant_id}"
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  network_acls {
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules       = "${split(",", azurerm_function_app.function.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)}"
  }

  tags = {
    asset-code    = "${var.storage_tags["asset_code"]}"
    module-code   = "${var.storage_tags["module_code"]}"
    environment   = "${var.environment}"
    instance-code = "${var.storage_tags["instance_code"]}"
    source        = "terraform"
  }
}
```

This comes back with the error "ip_rules must be a list".

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your Terraform code and the exact error you get please? It might also be useful to show the output of the outbound IP addresses from the function app if possible.

Comment: Hard to give exact details as the pipeline has expired and gone and i've got around it by removing the firewalls which isn't ideal, however i can give a bit (i'll update the main post now)

Comment: Can you also share the output from the `azurerm_function_app` resource please? Either adding it as an output or running `terraform state show azurerm_function_app.function.possible_outbound_ip_addresses`

Comment: I would agree that the exported attribute `azurerm_function_app.function.possible_outbound_ip_addresses` is a likely culprit here.

Comment: Its all ran via jenkins, so a bit hard to get access to everything. I did put the possible_outbound_ip_addresses in to a tag and it was in the form of 0.0.0.0,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3. Someone else has had a similar issue here: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-0-12-azurerm-app-service-outputs-as-azurerm-mysql-firewall-rule-inputs/3054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are seeing here is a classic Terraform 0.11 design flaw: when a value is unknown at plan time (because it will be decided only during apply), Terraform 0.11 can't properly track the type information for it.

Because `possible_outbound_ip_addresses` is an unknown value at planning time, the result of `split` with that string is also unknown. Because Terraform doesn't track type information for that result, the provider SDK code rejects that unknown value because it isn't a list.

To address this in Terraform 0.11 requires doing your initial run with the `-target` argument so that Terraform can focus on creating the function (and thus allocating its outbound IP addresses) first, and then deal with the processing of that string separately once it's known:

```
terraform apply -target=azurerm_function_app.function
terraform apply # to complete the rest of the work that -target excluded
```

Terraform 0.12 addressed this limitation by tracking type information for both known and unknown values, so in Terraform 0.12 the `split` function would see that you gave it an unknown string and accept that as being correctly typed, and then it would return an unknown *list of strings* to serve as a placeholder for the result that will be finally determined during the apply phase.

Comment: What about the plan stage

Comment: Terraform v0.11 is obsolete, and this answer only applies to Terraform v0.11 or earlier. If you are using those versions, the best answer is to upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If is var.string is `1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8`-

`split(',', var.string)[0]` should give you back `1.2.3.4` as a string. Your questions is difficult without an example.

Comment: I'm trying to use the output to populate a whitelist, so for example to add all of the returned ips to a firewall rule. Not just 1 of them. So although what you have put would work probably for 1 it wouldn't of all of the ips. I can't just omit the [0] as it complains it's not a list

Comment: split() definitely outputs lists. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/split.html .

Comment: It does but if you try to use it in conjunction with the IP rules I've just linked to, it complains it's not a List

Comment: You mentioned tf 0.11, so my guess is that it's syntax-related.

Comment: I've tried multiple ways,  but nothing seems to work, doesn't really make any sense. The simple way should just be: ip_rules: "${split(",", azurerm_function_app.function.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)}" not sure how it can complain it's not a list... I think I did the same in to a tag and it said it must be a string and not an interface... Whereas I would have expected should be a string not a list so it's like it's a non parsable list.. probably something similar to https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-0-12-azurerm-app-service-outputs-as-azurerm-mysql-firewall-rule-inputs/3054

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I can get a list of possible IPs

create a data source and then a locals var

```
app_services = [ "app1", "app2", "app3" ]

data "azurerm_app_service" "outbound_ips" {
  count                = length(var.app_services)
  name                 = var.app_services[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = var.server_resource_group_name
}

locals {
  apps_outbound_ips = distinct(flatten(concat(data.azurerm_app_service.outbound_ips.*.possible_outbound_ip_address_list)))
}
```

You don't have to use a data source either, if you are building the resource just use the outputs instead of  a data source, in my case I use a data source as I build my apps separately.

Works flawlessly for me and produces a list of strings (Strings being each unique outbound IP of the set of app services / function apps) in the form of `local.apps_outbound_ips`

Enjoy :)